# I want wordpress as a complete website

Tags: php, wordpress

I used wordpress to develop a site but what i got in result was just a blog. how can i make a complete website like for example BBC's website using wordpress.I have a basic knowledge of HTML,CSS and PHP. How can i built a complete website(beyonf blog) with wordpress?

Comment: like the BBC? got a few million pounds? wordpress is a CMS, just look around the wordpress site to see what you can do with it (especially the Showcase section).

Comment: Wordpress is ideal for making blog website but there are lots of plugins available which satisfy your requirement. If still you want more functionalities , create your own plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pages` to generate a webpage blog. You have to link to this pages, this is possible through the theme.

Have a look here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages

And as seferov said choose a nice theme.

Comment: thank you. Its quite helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Just pick a good theme. There are tons of wordpress themes look like BBC's website

Answer (score -1):

The first sentence in your question is quite disturbing. First off you need to get an idea of what you want to accomplish and be aware of the tools you have available. Maybe WordPress isn't the right tool for this project.

If you want to create a website which is beyond a blog with WordPress you will need to know how to create a website without WordPress. If you in your web development solely rely on plugins, and code already been written you will soon run into a wall, or fail miserably.

Find out what to want to accomplish. Set up goals. Look over the work that has to be done. Ask yourself if you have what it takes to meet your goals.

Comment: i think this should be a comment, than an answer... :)